# How to select 3rd list items with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to get 3rd li elements in java script

i want select 3rd li element using java script

```
<ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **[`:nth-child(3)`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)** to select third child

As you were tagged jquery

```js
$('ul li:nth-child(3)').css('color', 'red')
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Or using pure JavaScript using **[`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)**

```js
document.querySelector('ul li:nth-child(3)').style.color = 'red';
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: what is mean by "querySelector"

Comment: @VinodReddy : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 2):

you can use below javascript code to select 3rd element in list -

```
var listElem = document.getElementsByTagName("li")[2];
```